# Angular 1.7.2/Spring Boot - Infinite template loading when include navbar and footer

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

My project was migrated from Thymeleaf to Angular. Navbar and footer is being included from another files on all pages. What is interesting - navbar/footer works on most of pages, without Home Page, Login Page and Thank You For Register Page. Aforementioned pages don't load navbar/footer (HTML status 302) and we can see fields from login page in the background for a moment. Moreover browser works very slowly and show warning:

```
WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once.
```

On the screen we can see navbar and fragment of footer on HomePage because I used Thymeleaf for problematic Login Page temporarily and were loaded they from there.

[image]

index.html (Home Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>MyBoldGoals</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body class="loading">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>

    <div ng-include="'navbar.htm'"></div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bg"></div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="main">

            <header id="header">
                <h1>MyBoldGoals</h1>
                <p>Set goals &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Achieve the objectives &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Win</p>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://github.com/scartout" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=https://github.com/scartout" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://github.com/scartout" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <footer id="footer">
                <span class="copyright">&copy; 2018 Developed by Pawel Dudek </span>
                <span class="copyright">&copy; Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</span>
            </footer>

        </div>
    </div>

<div ng-include="'footer.htm'"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think UserController.java cause a problem:

```
package pl.scartout.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import pl.scartout.model.User;
import pl.scartout.repo.UserRepo;
import pl.scartout.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService, UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user,
            BindingResult bindResult) {
        if(bindResult.hasErrors())
            return "login";
        else {
            if (userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername())==null) {
                userService.addWithDefaultRole(user);
                return "thankyou";
            }
            else return "login";

        }
    }

}
```

HomeController.java

```
package pl.scartout.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "home";
        }

    }
```

Full project may clone from: [Link](https://github.com/scartout/BoldGoals) You have to make changes (add ng-app="" because I used Thymeleaf for problematic pages temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `ng-app` within the `<body>`. It should be inside of `<div>` tag within the body. This will tell the app where to load the content. It won't work where you have it now because the scripts are being loaded after you have initiated the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem. Additional info - if 'login' method in UserController.java is commented out, we can't see login fields in background, navbar still isn't loaded and HomePage title has proper attributes (when isn't commented out, main.css isn't loaded).